# What is the difference between normal extension and splitting field of a polynomial over a given field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reading a book on field theory and found the definition of normal extension of a field and I found that it is just like the definition of a splitting field of a polynomial over a field. So I can't find the reason why we need to study two things while they are same. Please reply.

Answer (score 1):

These are close concepts, but not the same. The two are equivalent only for finite extensions. There are however infinite normal extensions. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993274/example-of-a-normal-extension).